# Error connecting android wear emulator: adb server didn't ack

Tags: watchface

I am trying to connect Android Wear emulator to my Android phone through USB cable. I am enterying the command:

```
adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601
```

And I get the following error:

```
adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: 
error:
```

Adb version:

```
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32
```

I also have installed these addition things:

```
$ sudo apt-get install lib64stdc++6 (if it is not installed)
$ cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++
$ mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.original
$ ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 ~/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++
$ sudo apt-get install mesa-utils (if it is not installed)
```

But still, even when I enter the commands below, all I see in Android Wear is "trying to connect..."

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601
```